# How much memory is used when allocating an array vs allocating an linked list in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, linked-list

My guess is its a 32-bit/64-bit word (depending on the CPU)  per value stored in the array.
So it would be array size X 32-bit/64-bit.

In the case of linked lists, it would be twice this to store the reference which points to the next element.
So it would be 2 * array size X 32-bit/64-bit.

Is this correct, am I missing anything?

Comment: It's a doubly linked list so you'll have a reference to the node before and after

Comment: Each independent link in the linked list is a separate object, with a minimum of an 8-byte header -- usually 12-16 -- in addition to the link fields.  There are ways to "fake" this using multiple arrays, but they are complicated, and at least the (old) version of LinkedList I checked does not do this.

Comment: a bit oiff topic, but consider using an Arraylist instead of an LinkedList, it uses less memory, if you call trim() it uses the same size as the array (some constant bytes more for list admin).

Answer (score 7):

Much more. Each element in a linked list has:

- Pointer to next element, pointer to previous element, pointer to item value (12 bytes) + object overhead (around another 12 bytes). Say 24 bytes.
- Each element is not primitive but a wrapper. If every element is different, it will occupy space. For integers say another 16 bytes.

Total: 40 bytes per element.

Don't take this at face value, it's just to give you an idea. If you want precise numbers fire up a memory analysis tool (e.g. Eclipse MAT).

Comment: `s/array list/LinkedList/g`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "wrapper".  Each element is a separate object, with a full object header.

Comment: @HotLicks That's what he's saying. The example linked list contains `Integer` objects, while an array can contain `int`s directly.

Comment: he meant a wrapper object: int -> Integer: 4bytes -> 4 + 12 = 16 bytes

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for this sort of thing, is there a Java link from Oracle that explains how much memory is used when creating java objects?

Comment: I mean each list entry itself is a separate object.  This has nothing to do with objects used to "box" primitives -- that would be additional overhead still.

Answer (score 1):

I made an [experiment](https://github.com/chaschev/experiments-with-microbes/blob/master/src/test/java/com/chaschev/microbe/samples/MemConsumptionTest.java#L185) on memory consumption of arrays. Here are the results for 20000 ints arrays:

```
    
OS: Windows 8 6.2, amd64
JVM: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.0-b56

                   x |          min |          avg |          max |       stddev
       total cpu, ms |     7.000000 |     8.250000 |    10.000000 |     0.829156
bytes per LinkedList |    830.48 KB |    830.48 KB |    830.48 KB |      0.50  B
      bytes per item |     42.00  B |     42.00  B |     42.00  B |      0.00  B

       total cpu, ms |     4.000000 |     6.000000 |     7.000000 |     0.547723
 bytes per ArrayList |    416.00 KB |    416.00 KB |    416.00 KB |      0.00  B
      bytes per item |     21.00  B |     21.00  B |     21.00  B |      0.00  B

       total cpu, ms |     0.000000 |     0.950000 |     1.000000 |     0.217945
byt per TIntArrayList|    105.56 KB |    105.56 KB |    105.56 KB |      0.00  B
      bytes per item |      5.00  B |      5.00  B |      5.00  B |      0.00  B
```

So it's

```
LinkedList:    42 bytes 
ArrayList:     21 bytes 
TIntArrayList: 5 bytes
```

However if the size of the array list is unknown, the resulting memory consumption due to array reallocation is:

```
LinkedList:    42 bytes
ArrayList:     29 bytes
TIntArrayList: 10 bytes
```