# Why stack using array why not linkedlist

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

Why Stack is implemented using array not using linkedlist ?

If you use add to front and remove from front in the linkedlist than it can be efficient way of of implementing stack, instead of working about increasing the size of the array when it's 75% or some threshold full.

Comment: Yeah, don't use `Stack`. `LinkedList` itself actually has the right methods to be used as a stack, so that would do if you really want a `LinkedList`-backed stack.

Comment: That said, the amortized overhead of expanding the array is offset by the improved locality of reference of an array, the reduced object overhead (an array is cheaper than a bunch of linked list nodes), and the lower cost of pushing or popping when you don't have to expand the array.

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-future-generations-will

Comment: A stack can be implemented many different ways.  The implementers of Stack chose to use an array, based on their priorities.  Others may have different priorities.

Comment: Amir's link is now https://dzone.com/articles/why-future-generations-will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you use add to front and remove from front in the linkedlist than it can be efficient way of of implementing stack, instead of working about increasing the size of the array when its 75% or some threshold full.

The trade-offs are more complicated than that.

- A stack that is implement using a linked list would need 3 or 4 times as much space per stack entry as an array-based implementation:

  - In an array-based implementation, a stack element just requires one reference-sized array cell.
  - In a linked-list based implementation, each stack element consists of a "node" object containing 2 references (or 3 if doubly-linked).  Then you have to add the overhead of the node's object header and possible heap node padding.

  <sup>You may waste some space due to resizing, but *on average* the math says that the wastage is much less than the "node" overheads.  If you are not prepared to take my word for this, do the math yourself for various combinations of platform assumptions; e.g. reference size, object header size, heap node size granularity, array resize strategy, etc.</sup>
- An array-based stack has predictable locality, whereas the objects that represent a linked list's entries could be scattered throughout the heap.
- If you expand an array-based data structure by a fixed percentage when it gets full, AND the stack has a long life, THEN the cost of the expansion is amortized, and becomes irrelevant.

On the flip-side a linked-list based implementation does have the advantage that space gets released (i.e. becomes eligible for GCing) when the stack empties.

In short, different implementation approaches will be better depending on how the stack is going to be used.  But the `Stack` implementors had to pick just one.

---

The other point is that `Stack` is a really old class that existed in Java 1.0 ... before the collections framework was introduced.  The API and aspects of the implementation are constrained by the need for backwards compatibility.

If you want better APIs and better (or different) performance characteristics, look at the classes that implement the `Dequeue` interface.

Comment: `A stack that is implement using a linked list would need 3 or 4 times as much space per stack entry as an array-based implementation`. Can you please explain what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Look at the implementation code.  The short explanation is "more objects, more fields".  And read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322173/how-much-memory-is-used-when-allocating-an-array-vs-allocating-an-linked-list-in

Answer (score 0):

Stack does not need access to the first element, push / pop / peek work only with the last element and array is good for that.

Comment: So is a linked list implementation with a tail reference, in terms of only accessing the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Linked lists require extra memory to store pointers to the next element, which can be less memory efficient than arrays.